# Assigning a keyboard shortcut to open an application with administrative privileges in windows 7.

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I know how to assign a keyboard shortcut to an application by

- Right click on the application and take properties.
- Under "Shortcut key", assign the shortcut pressing the key combination.

But how can I open the same application with the shortcut key combination 
with administrator privileges?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AHK (AutoHotkey) and make a script that does this

This will open Itunes if you do Windows + Alt + P

```
#!P::
    Run "C:\Program Files\itunes\iTunes.exe"
    Return
```

Comment: Absolutely agree with this answer. AHK is the solution here! Sathyam you can change the shortcut to whatever you like it to be. Just put whatever shortcut you like prior to the '::' at the start of the script.